# SQL Server Reporting Services 2017 Cant connect and doesnt show in Configuration Manager

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, sql-server-2017

I have a few question about SSRS 2017 that I cant find answers to.

Can you no longer add it to the default instance?  It seems to force it to an instance called SSRS

After doing the configuration steps I am still not able to connect to SSRS through mangement studio, it says it cant find a sql server reporting instance.  If I go to browse it does see it under defaultinstance/SSRS but I cant connect.

I cannot see SSRS listed under the configuration manager.

I can connect through the Reporting services configuration manager and I can load the reports page.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: SQL Server Error]

[image: Seen in browse]

Comment: I have answered this question in my own post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49308578/ssms-cant-connect-to-ssrs). If you haven't resolved this, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you done all the required steps of the installation?

Could you compare your steps with this link post?
[Installing SQL Server Reporting Services 2017](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5237/installing-sql-server-reporting-services-2017/) (MSSQLTips.com)
Do you notice any differences?

Also check this resource:
[What’s New in Reporting Services (SSRS) 2017](https://www.sqlshack.com/whats-new-reporting-services-ssrs-2017/) (SQLShack.com)

> ...because if you try to connect to a SQL 2017 Reporting Services instance or Power BI Report Server instance with anything less than Management Studio 17 (grab it, its free!) you’ll receive this nasty error:
>
> [image: Your error message] 
>   <sub>*The error message on the web site resembles your own error message*</sub>
>
> Don’t worry, your instance is there & (likely) online. Once you have SSMS 17 or higher you’ll be able to connect ...

Comment: INFO: Links become obsolete so it's better to add some portion of the material you are referencing. If the link dies, the information is still valid and available. Some times link only answers get deleted. I opted to spice up your answer to show you how it works. Enjoy the reputation.